# No /dev/null on Fedora 17

Tags: fedora

I'm running `Fedora 17` and `/dev/null` does not exist, why not?

Should I just create it with:

```
mknod -m 666 /dev/null c 1 3
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no harm in creating it if it isn't there already.

The real question is why it isn't there. What do you get when you say `df -h /dev`? How about `ps -eaf | grep udevd`?

Comment: I don't know what happened but after running `mount` the `/dev` directory looked as expected with all the devices appearing, I'm not sure why `/dev` was only showing a few things before?

Comment: I wouldn't just leave it at that. The problem is likely to come back on the next reboot, since `/dev` is now completely dynamic. `mknod` hackery is no longer persistent, as it once was on Unices. I would [reboot the system in single-user mode](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Installation_Guide/s1-rescuemode-booting-single.html) and pay careful attention to the messages dealing with `/dev/` or `udev` you get on startup. Then when it's up, `ls -l /dev` again. If `/dev/null` and others are still missing, run the commands I recommended, adding their output to your question.

Comment: Thanks Warren, I will follow your advice and update the question as appropriate.

Comment: you could run in all sorts of trouble at boot if you lack /dev/null ... prepare a bootable distribution on CD to help you sort it out... (you will then probably need to mount the relevant partitions to some /tmp/directory(s), and ensure once you chroot into the main one you'll be able to access the commands you'll need to fix everything up)